# Assigining type to dynamically accessed object values

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, types

I have created a class which has 2 properties storing arrays of tuples with numbers. I also have created a method "getIndex" that accesses those properties dynamically and then checks whether there is a tuple containing identical numbers. The function looks like this:

```
  getIndex(posX: number, posY: number, pathArr: string) {
    for (let routeCoordinates of this[pathArr]) {
      if (routeCoordinates[0] === posX && routeCoordinates[1] === posY) {
        return this[pathArr].indexOf(routeCoordinates);
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that whenever I try to pass pathArr as a key I get the following error message:

> "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PathfinderSecondStage'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PathfinderSecondStage'."

I know about generics but solutions I found on the internet do not work as I am dealing with a class instance. Is there a solution that keeps typechecking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate solution is pretty simple. All you need to do is change `pathArr: string` parameter to `pathArr: keyof PathfinderSecondStage` which will cause TypeScript to create a union type of all the public fields/methods within the class and then extract the  `this[pathArr]` statement and assign it into a variable with the assistance of type assertion to tell it the exact type that is going to be used:

```
 getIndex(posX: number, posY: number, pathArr: keyof PathfinderSecondStage) {
    const myArray = this[pathArr] as number[][];
    for (let routeCoordinates of myArray) {
      if (routeCoordinates[0] === posX && routeCoordinates[1] === posY) {
        return myArray.indexOf(routeCoordinates);
      }
    }
  }
```

You can additionally narrow down the allowed variables for the `pathArr` parameter by specifically defining the names of the fields that contain the arrays which can be traversed within the function as below:
`getIndex(posX: number, posY: number, pathArr: 'fieldName1'|'fieldName2') {`

This will narrow down the number of types TypeScript needs to create a union type with, and if they are all arrays of numbers (`number[][]`), you will not need to do the type assertion as displayed in the first example.

Comment: The solution has worked for me. Big thanks!

Comment: Also additionally I store variables for paths in a separate settings file as strings, so in order to narrow them down i used "as const" to let typescript know that these are not going to be changed and then it worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code it is impossible to know what `this[]` refers to, but you can allow a Typescript array to be indexed with strings by declaring it as `let ARRAY: { [key: string]: DTYPE; } = {};` where ARRAY is your array name and DTYPE is the data type you are storing.